# Trouble Installing ubuntu..USB.. Picture below

Tags: installation, 13.04, usb, nomodeset

Ok so I've spent all day trying to figure out the problem and still can't figure out what's up.. So first I thought the main problem was the screen goes black after I hit "install ubuntu".. So I look through some posts and figure out I just need to put "nomodestep" after splash... Well that didn't work so I compared my screen to the one in the tutorial and it's totally different. My list of "code" or whatever is about 3 lines long.. The ones in the tutorial is a whole page worth of different stuff.

So to recap, when I try to install ubuntu the screen goes black and when I try to edit the code I'm getting a totally different screen with totally different "code". 
I don't know what to do and I can't find any other tutorials containing this problem.
Btw, I tried 12.04 and 13.04 and I followed the directions exactly so I don't think that's a problem.

Here's the screen I get when I try to edit:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be `nomodeset` not `nomodestep`
but...
you could also try:

```
nomodeset xforcevesa
```

or

```
nomodeset GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024x32
```

However, these are work-arounds, and the end result is not optimal... i.e. the screen is not crisp and clear.